# Checkinstall fails to make a Ruby 1.9.2 package

Tags: ruby, checkinstall

Checkinstall fails to make a Ruby package with the following error.

```
# checkinstall -D --install=no --pakdir=/home/<username>/Рабочий\ стол/

<...>

installing binary commands:   /usr/local/bin
/home/<username>/Рабочий стол/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/fileutils.rb:854:in `utime': No such file or directory - /usr/local/bin/ruby (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /home/<username>/Рабочий стол/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/fileutils.rb:854:in `block in install'
    from /home/<username>/Рабочий стол/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/fileutils.rb:1423:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
    from /home/<username>/Рабочий стол/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/fileutils.rb:1437:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
    from /home/<username>/Рабочий стол/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/fileutils.rb:1421:in `fu_each_src_dest'
    from /home/<username>/Рабочий стол/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/fileutils.rb:850:in `install'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:154:in `install'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:307:in `block in '
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:542:in `call'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:542:in `block (2 levels) in '
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:539:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:539:in `block in '
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:535:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:535:in `'
make: *** [do-install-all] Ошибка 1

****  Установка неудачна. Отменяется создание пакета.

Очищается.../usr/bin/checkinstall: line 328: [: /home/<username>/Рабочий: ожидается использование бинарного оператора
OK

Удачи.
```

What is the cause of the problem? How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.1;

Ruby 1.9.2;

Checkinstall 1.6.2.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue using Ubuntu 11.04.

I believe this is caused in part by a permissions error (need to run as root). It also appears to be affected by a checkinstall fstrans bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/checkinstall/+bug/78455

Original command (fails):

sudo checkinstall --install=no -D make install

Working command:

sudo checkinstall --fstrans=no -D make install

Comment: Actually, it turns out this package doesn't include the binaries. WTF!?

Comment: Actually, I used the -D option too. I don't know why I specified the -R option in the exapmle of the question. It's nessesary to correct it.

Comment: As for my question, it seems that it's impossible to make a package without modifying the system, so it needs to use the `--install=yes` and `--fstrans=no` options. I solve the problem that way. Despite the Ruby interpreter is installed not from a package it's still possible to uninstall it using a package manager (Aptitude in my case).

Comment: Just in case, here's the full command which has worked for me `# checkinstall --type=debian --install=yes --fstrans=no --pakdir='..'`.

Comment: Yeah, check [this checkinstall bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/checkinstall/+bug/78455) out.